# First line of Datagridview is replaced on button click

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to add a new row to my `DataGridView` with values from five `TextBox`es on a button click. The issue is that when I click the button, the values are inserted, but replacing the first line of my `DataGridView`.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim D As New DataTable
    D.Columns.Add("CODIGO")
    D.Columns.Add("NOMBRE")
    D.Columns.Add("BULTOS")
    D.Columns.Add("CANTIDAD")
    D.Columns.Add("PRECIO")
    Detalle_VDataGridView.DataSource = D
    Dim R As DataRow
    R = D.NewRow
    R("CODIGO") = CODIGOTextBox.Text
    R("NOMBRE") = NOMBRETextBox.Text
    R("BULTOS") = TextBox4_Cantidad.Text
    R("CANTIDAD") = TextBox3_CantFinal.Text
    R("PRECIO") = PRECIOTextBox.Text
    D.Rows.Add(R)
End Sub
```

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: You are replacing the entire datasource on each click

Comment: Please read [ask], take the time to format your code so we can read it, and take the [Tour] to learn how SO works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because for every button click you're creating a new `DataTable`

```
Dim D As New DataTable
```

This line here is the reason. Declare this `DataTable` at class level and a new row, then your code will be fine.

Comment: No problem, you should accept the answer to show that it was what solved the issue, in case other people have the same issue in the future.